# passing multidimensional array ajax laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

i would like to passing data from my javascript function and send it into controller this is my code

**ajax.js**

```
let dataNewMemoData = JSON.stringify(createnewMemoData);

$.ajax({
    url: '/crew_memo/submitdata',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'json',
    data: {data: dataNewMemoData},
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    success : function(data){
       console.log(data) 
    },
    error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,thrownError){
     console.log(jqXHR)
    }
})
```

this is my route from web

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/crew_memo/submitdata', 'CrewProgramController@saveData');
```

**controller.php**

```
public function saveData(Request $request){
    $getData = $request->tableplacement->employeNik;
    return dd($getData);
}
```

i want to access this value, so basically i want to access value inside array on array

[image]

i want to access emplyeNik or any other value inside that array how can i do that

Comment: i would like to access it in laravel controller

Comment: i got an error Trying to get property 'tableplacement' of non-object

Comment: this is an image error https://imgur.com/A6ZvWau

Comment: @AndySong this is the image https://imgur.com/tlfoizw, i got Call to a member function all() on null

Comment: yeah i already import this Request ```use Illuminate\Http\Request;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do.

```php
foreach (request()->input('tableplacement') as $value) {
   //$value is each item in the array.

}
```

Comment: i got this https://imgur.com/oSFkyEv, invalid argument supplied for foreach